Baffled! Copy/Paste not Working after running simple macro that replaces paragraph breaks with line breaks
As part of a work process, I'm asked to run this macro and when it's completed, select all, copy the contents, and paste it into another document. After running the macro, I can select all, but as soon as I attempt to copy, Word freezes, crashes, and shuts down. Why is this happening?
    Sub KK_RUN
    '
    ' Kk_RUN Macro
    '
    '
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^l"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub

I have already reinstalled/repaired my Word. [Word for Microsoft 365 (Version 2407)]
There are no calculations in the document. It's all text. I have tried starting Word in safe mode and it still happens.

What does Event Viewer say is the reason Word is crashing? Have you spoken with your IT support staff at your org regarding this?

Just in case: if you are not actually "running" the macro but are stepping through it (perhaps to test it) then some operations definitely will not succeed until you have stepped all the way through.
